# Porquê 'da Rio 2016' em vez de 'do Rio 2016' em PT-BR?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gênero

Estive a ler uns artigos sobre os jogos olímpicos no Rio de Janeiro em 2016, e nos escritos em PT-BR, li várias vezes 'da Rio 2016' em vez de 'do Rio 2016'? Porque razão é utilizado o género feminino?

[Um exemplo](https://esportes.terra.com.br/jogos-olimpicos/2016/basquete-dos-eua-confirma-lista-e-divulga-equipe-que-jogara-as-olimpiadas,89ec3e0f1a375b0d126af0e25daffc8cb821c2w8.html) (ênfase minha):

> Basquete masculino dos EUA confirma elenco para **a Rio 2016**

Comment: Old Man, incluí o exemplo propriamente dito, para o pessoa poder ler sem ter que visitar a página. Já agora, eu não encontrei ***da Rio*** nessa página, só ***a Rio***.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Da (Olimpíada) Rio 2016. O termo elidido é feminino, e pede artigo feminino.

Comment: Do mesmo modo, apesar de *Portugal* não levar artigo (diz-se *sou **de** Portugal*, não ***do** Portugal*) encontramos [*do Portugal 2004*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22do+portugal+2004%22&oq=%22do+portugal+2004%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30l7.16976.17484.0.18319.2.2.0.0.0.0.75.145.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.70.Z4uet3oE2Xc) por *do campeonato da UEFA Portugal 2004*.

Comment: E [*no África do Sul 2010*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22no+%C3%81frica+do+Sul+2010%22&oq=%22no+%C3%81frica+do+Sul+2010%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l10.27593.40589.0.43594.27.25.2.0.0.0.98.2002.25.25.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.22.1641...0j0i3j0i10j0i22i10i30j0i8i13i30.1yUf0T-qAps). Eu acrescentaria era um exemplo da net à resposta em que se visse claramente que *da Rio 2016*  é usado no lugar de *da Olimpíada Rio 2016*.

Comment: Esta resposta podia ser melhorada; mas eu não encontro uma boa edição.

Answer (score 6):

Foi utilizada uma figura de linguagem chamada de elipse, ocultou-se o termo 'olimpíada'.

> Ex.:
>    da **olimpíada** Rio 2016

Comment: Os Jornalistas brasileiros usam muito esta figura de linguagem.

Answer (score 2):

Sem ter encontrado uma fonte para dar como refêrencia, acredito ter sido escolhido o artigo feminino para evitar ambiguidade. Uma vez que Rio é um substantivo masculino, "Rio 2016" soa mais como uma congregação na cidade do Rio de Janeiro, seja por causa de um congresso, uma reunião de cúpula, um campeonato mundial ou, nesse caso, os Jogos Olímpicos. "O Rio 2016", sem esse contraste, poderia soar ambíguo.

ADDENDUM - Outros eventos ocorridos no Rio de Janeiro como a ECO 92 (World Summit - encontro internacional para debater os problemas ambientais) ficou conhecida como **a Rio 92**.

Na língua falada, "o Rio 2016" pode ser confundido com "o rio Dois Mil e....", o nome de um rio. É claro que no momento em que completarmos "....e dezesseis", a grande maioria das pessoas já percebeu que não é o nome de um rio. O início da frase, no entanto, pode fazer alguém pensar tratar-se de um rio. No momento em que se fala "a Rio..." já fica claro que não se trata de "um rio". Houve a ECO 92 que ficou conhecida como "a Rio 92" e o uso do artigo no feminino remete a encontros, congressos, campeonatos, etc.

Comment: Estive a ler mais alguns.... talvez também possa ser relativo às Olimpíadas, não?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Sim, pode ser.  Mas tanto "Olimpíadas" como "Jogos Olímpicos" estâo no plural.  Além disso, outros eventos ocorridos no Rio de Janeiro como a ECO 92 (World Summit - encontro internacional para debater os problemas ambientais) ficou conhecida como **a** Rio 92.

Comment: Bem visto, Centaurus!

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Na net encontro muito mais [conferência Rio 92](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22confer%C3%AAncia+rio+92%22&num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=585&ei=F_WHV87VL8KMUdr3nOgN&start=250&sa=N) que [encontro rio 92](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22encontro+rio+92%22&oq=%22encontro+rio+92%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30j0i30.81777.81920.0.83116.2.2.0.0.0.0.85.156.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.154...0i8i13i30j0i13i30.1b10fNu0_ns), 280 contra 50. Também encontro ***o** Rio 92*.

Comment: @Jacinto Acho que Luis Henrique tem a resposta correta.  Contudo, esse tipo de pergunta dificilmente permite que apresentemos uma referência "to back up our view".

Comment: Não percebo como é que chegas à conclusão que evita ambiguidade, @Centaurus. A tua resposta não mo clarifica. Quando muito, reduz para metade as coisas a que se pode estar a referir, ao cortar as masculinas; mas como muitas vezes a mesma coisa pode ser referida por sinónimos masculinos e femininos, nem isso... (a competição, o campeonato?)

Comment: @ANeves  Na língua falada, "o Rio 2016" pode ser confundido com "o rio Dois Mil e....", o nome de um rio.  É claro que no momento em que completarmos "....e dezesseis", a grande maioria das pessoas já percebeu que não é o nome de um rio.  Mas o início da frase pode fazer alguém pensar tratar-se de um rio.    No momento em que se fala "a Rio..." já fica claro que não estamos nos referindo a "um rio".  Houve a ECO 92 que ficou conhecida como "a Rio 92"  e o uso do artigo no feminino remete a encontros, congressos, campeonatos, etc.

Comment: Ah, estou a perceber. Não acho o argumento convincente; acho que a linguagem é rápida demais para se entender mal «Rio ...» antes de se ouvir «... 92» e se perceber o nome; acho que se ouve tudo de uma vez.

Comment: Centaurus concordo com o @ANeves o argumento das outras respostas é bem mais convincente do que o seu. Podes estar certo, mas acho que precisas de alguma fonte de conhecimento para provar a tua teoria.

Comment: @JorgeB. Também acho o argumento do Luis Henrique mais convincente, embora não haja concordância em número ("as Olimpíadas" x "a Rio 92").  No Brasil é bem mais comum ouvirmos "as Olimpíadas de 2016" ou "Os Jogos Olímpicos de 2016", do que "a Olimpíada de 2016".  Se a resposta do Luis Henrique tivesse sido postada antes da minha, talvez eu não tivesse respondido à pergunta.  Mas quando postei, não havia ainda nenhuma resposta, entendes?  A terceira resposta postada foi uma cópia da segunda e, na minha modesta opinião, deveria ter sido deletada.

Comment: ECO 92 era conferência